# "NO" answer in Siri Extension kills it

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit, ios-extensions

I did a Siri Extension for my app. In this extension I ask people questions and save their answers to the app. If the user answers "No" on some of my question the Siri Extensions stops the process. Siri kills my Extension. This question is "Would you like to add an additional info?". How can I override this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will be straggling with the same problem. It is possible to add a Enum to your intent with Yes and No options or use INBooleanResolution